# How to customize date item with circular border in react-calendar?

Tags: reactjs, calendar, datasource

Currently, I'm using react-calendar for a custom styled calendar in my project.
I want to customize each date item with a circular border like the image below.

[image]

My dataSources is

```
type SourceType = {
    title: string,
    startDate: Date,
    endDate: Date,
    color: 'red' | 'blue'
}

dataSources: SourceType[]
```

and React-Calendar component is

```
import Calendar from 'react-calendar'
...
const [selectedDate, setSelectedDate] = React.useState(new Date())
...
<Calendar
    view='month'
    onChange={setSelectedDate}
    value={selectedDate}
/>
```

Please share your solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use tileClassName property of react-calendar. Here is my solution:

```
  import moment from 'moment';
  ...
  <Calendar
    view='month'
    onChange={setSelectedDate}
    value={selectedDate}
    tileClassName={({ date, view }: CalendarTileProperties) => {
        let resClassName = ''
        if (dataSources.find(x => (moment(x.startDate).format("DD-MM-YYYY") === moment(date).format("DD-MM-YYYY")) && (x.color === 'red'))) {
            resClassName += ' red_item'
        }
        if (dataSources.find(x => (moment(x.startDate).format("DD-MM-YYYY") === moment(date).format("DD-MM-YYYY")) && (x.color === 'blue'))) {
            resClassName += ' blue_item'
        }
        return resClassName
    }}
  />
```

and insert the following scss code:

```
.calendar {
    .month-container {
        .day {
            .day-content {
                padding: 3px 6px;
                border-radius: 50%;

                &.blue_item {
                    border: 2px solid blue;
                }

                &.red_item {
                    border: 2px solid red;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```